# DataTables does not display received data

Tags: jquery, flask, post, datatables

I created a table, data processing is done from the server side (FLASK). I needed to change from `GET` request to `POST` because the table is extremely large and at some point the `GET` request had become too large. Flask processes the request and sends the data back, from the console I see that the data has been received but it is not shown in the table and the table shows "Processing..." all the time.

I specify that with `get` everything works.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#data tfoot th').each(function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html('<input type="text" class="col-search-input" placeholder="Search"' + title + '"/>');
    });

    var addedRows;
    var MyTable = $('#data').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    serverSide: true,
    processing:true,
    ajax: {
      url: "{{ url_for('cdf.data') }}",
      type:'POST',
      dataType:"json",
      data:"data"
    },
    "scrollX": true, 
    "scrollY": true,
    
    //paging:false,
    style :"width:100%;",
    fixedColumns :{
      left:4,
      right: 0
    },
    columns: [
    {data: 'counter', name: "counter"},
    ...
```

[response in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOW7D.png)

I tried to change the parameters of DataTables, sadly to no result.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why is this tagged with [tag:server-side] if you assume that the answer is sent back properly from the server?

Comment: I tried different configurations on datatables, and before that I tried changing the values that Flask returns. I know I get a response from the server and it seems correct but I can't rule out that there is something I am missing. I've read a lot of posts about it and I can't find any errors. I also tried updating the version of datatables I use but nothing changes there either. I am really running out of ideas.

Comment: You haven't shown us the structure of your JSON response (except in a summarized screenshot) but it does not appear, from what we can see, to match what `serverSide: true` expects. See the "returned data" section and related example [in the official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side).

Comment: (Also, with `serverSide: true`, you are only expected to send one page of results at a time. The `serverSide: true` setting is intended to deal with situations where the full volume of data causes performance issues. Your "too large" comments suggest Flask is not using the server-side approach correctly. Lots of guesswork here, because the question does not really show us the relevant info.)

Comment: What does the browser's web console say (not the network tab, but the console tab)? Any errors shown?

Comment: @andrewJames on the server side I don't have any performance problems, as you rightly point out I moved it to the server just to be able to work on that amount of data. What is too big was the request which depends on the size of the table (the table has really many columns) so the GET request is blocked by Apache. I know the value can be increased in apache's settings but it definitely can't be my final solution. In the console there are no errors, at least not new ones. In any case by momentarily increasing the value from apache I could see that with GET there is no problem.

Comment: data [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
draw null
recordsFiltered 85
recordsTotal 100

Comment: Thank you for the notes & clarifications. The `draw` parameter should not be `null` (but that wouldn't cause data to not load with POST, if you have seen that GET works).

Comment: I solved it, the problem is that by changing to POST I changed how to take all the parameters except the draw which I had missed.

Comment: @andrewJames Thank you very much! I realized the error by re-reading the documentation you sent

Comment: Nice - glad you solved it! You are welcome to [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), especially if you think it will help future visitors to your question. (Otherwise, you may consider deleting the question.)

Answer (score 1):

In changing from `GET` request to `POST` you have to change how you take the paramenters  and things like: (Python Flask)

```
x=request.args.get(f'columns[{i}][search][value]')
```

I changed them into:

```
par = dict(request.form)
x=par[f'columns[{i}][search][value]']
```

In my case, I had not noticed that `draw` remained as it was and returned a null value instead of an integer.

before:

```
'draw': request.args.get('draw', type=int)
```

after:

```
'draw': parameters['draw']
```